# Gitbook header add id and internal links

Tags: html, header, github-flavored-markdown, gitbook

I am new to the programming community and new to Gitbook. I have searched gitbook doc but still having some syntax problems.

I have been trying to add internal links so that, on a long web page, I can click links on the top of the page and it will directs me to content blocks contained in the bottom of the page. I also have a few long pages.

```
[Clickable Link1](redirects to headerId1 in the same page)
[Clickable Link2](redirects to headerId2 in the same page)
...

Real Content
Header 1 with id = headerId1
Content1

Header 2 with id = headerId2
Content2
...
```

The resources I had looked for involves:
https://gitbookio.gitbooks.io/markdown/content/syntax/links.html

The problems I am having is:

1. add id to headings.

   I tried to type `### Header1 {#id=myheader1}` After typing `###` and followed by a space, the `Header1 {#id=myheader1}` became big and shows as heading3 size texts. How do I escape and make sure it only shows `Header 1` with heading 1 font and assigned with id of header1?
2. Refer to internal headings
   I tried to follow the doc, but still, it only shows the original text with [] and does not turn into clickable links.

Please share some tips and help. Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you trying to build a table of contents for your page?

Comment: @Chris Yes. I found that I could use the insert link button on the top to insert page links, however, I do not want to have too many separate sub-pages. Instead, I hope I could link to different headers in the same page by clicking links on the top of the page. But I could not successfully assign ids to headers from the online/local edit tools. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly advise against manually building a table of contents. It's a pain to make them, and even more of a pain to maintain them.

Instead, let software take care of this for you. Here are two GitBook plugins that I just found for making tables of contents:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/gitbook-plugin-page-toc
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/gitbook-plugin-simple-page-toc

Plugins [can be enabled within the editor or by editing the `book.json` file.](https://help.gitbook.com/content/how-can-i-add-plugin.html)

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked a long time ago. Just in case anyone come across this because there is no official docs for this:

You could define your custom anchor to a header using the syntax `## My heading {#my-anchor}` and reference it normally with `[my text](#my-anchor)`. This will show the heading correctly as `My heading` and navigation will work properly.